# Customization of UWP Title Bar

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to extend the view to the title bar and set the same color as the page and I've had success extending the view but I just cannot find how to set the color.

What I've done:

On my app.xaml.cs file I have this function that is called on the OnLaunched method:

```cs
private void ExtendViewIntoTitleBar()
{
    CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.White;
    titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.White;
}
```

But I got this as result:

[image]

How can I change the color of this area marked in red?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi gmobrice, welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't help with your question, but I'd like to point out that SO offers the option to inlude images that are shown inline thus you don't need to click a link.

Comment: @MichaelA thanks for the tip! But I can only insert images inline after get at least 10 of reputation

Comment: I have tried your code but I could not reproduce your issue could you provide the sample with github that I could debug directly.

Comment: @gmobrice: thx for telling me. wasn't aware of this limit. Next time I'll do as Maifee did and just insert the figure for someone instead of being a Mr. Know it all :D

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the help, I kinda figured it out what I was doing wrong. 
I had a frame inside my NavigationView with a defined background, causing this grey bar, now everything is fine. Thank you! :)